# How to code svg text zooming?

Tags: html, svg

I have svg code which contains itemzoom property in text tag but when i opened in adobe illustrator tool it is not showing the text in zoomed effect. please help me to resolve this issue. I have to show the text in itemzoomed format.

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd" version="1.0"><rect style="fill:none;stroke:#373435;stroke-width:2.08346" width="500" height="500"/><g id="0.1778128929496472">        
    <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="0.7911494016479048">
<text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="translate(0.6590909090909091 0.7045454545454546)" fill="#000000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="194" y="420" text-anchor="left" font-size="90.75" font-family="Casablanca" data-textcurve="0" data-itemzoom="1 1" itemzoom="0.5050505050505051 0.543010752688172">Test</text>
</g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: The SVG specification has no such property as itemzoom.

Comment: How to give the zoom property for text

Comment: Is there any property to add like scaling or text transform matrix

Comment: transform="scale(2)" or whatever number you like instead of 2